# why can't we call tcsetattr function to set pseudo-terminal's setting when the calling process is running in the background?

Tags: linux, terminal

I am working on a project where I have to save and restore pseudoterminal's setting. I am able to use *tcgetattr* for saving the terminal settings even when the calling process is in the background.  However, the case is not same with *tcsetattr* function to restore the terminal settings, when the calling process is in background. It just hangs up on tcsetattr.

Do anyone know why this happens and can anyone suggest the idea how can I achieve terminal setting restoration for a background process?

**EDIT**

Circumstance: 
This is work-flow the sample program and I'm trying to take a snapshot of the program and restart it later:

```
main function
  -- opens a master pty with NOCTTY flag
  -- opens a slave pty with NOCTTY flag
  fork 
parent process
  -- close the slave and wait for child process
child process
  -- set up slave pty as a new controlling terminal
  -- saves controlling term setting i.e.slave
  -- run a while loop for 200 seconds (using SIGALARM) 
       and do some trivial task locally
```

Comment: Guess: Processes in the background are not supposed to modify terminal settings, because that would interfere with the process in the foreground (which may want its own terminal settings). Could you explain in more detail why and under what circumstances you have to save and restore pty settings?

Comment: I am trying to take a snapshot of a sample pty program and restart it from the snapshot later. So while taking a snapshot, I am saving all the settings and buffer of the ptys in a file and on the restart, I am setting those settings back to the new pair of ptys. However, as I mentioned *tcsetattr* is not working because, in my sample program, slaves becomes a controlling terminal in the child process after the fork.